# How to create the following View?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Staff Table

[image: Staff Table]

Payment Table

[image: Payment Table]

Here I can't upload the availability table. It consists of Availability_ID,Staff_ID and Shift_ID columns.

I want to Create a view which shows all details of all staff and their availability details.  The view should include the last name and first name of the staff member, the full name of their mentor (if any), their hourly salary and the days and times they are available for work? How can I create?

Comment: I only tried the following code:
"create view Staff_Availability AS
Select * from staff;"
It just showed the columns of staff table. but I want a view as I mentioned above. I think it has to add Inner join or Outer join methods.

Comment: 1. Self Left Join with Staff to get Mentor Details, 2. Inner Join Payment to get the HourlyPay, 3. Inner Join Availability to get ShiftID - 4. Inner join ShiftTABLE to get the Start Hour and End Hour

Comment: Try the above hints if you get any errors then let us know - but asking for complete solutions without trying is not the purpose of this site

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, you will get all the columns of your three tables.

```
SELECT * FROM Staff Inner Join Payment ON Staff.Payment_Id = Payment.Payment_Id Innjer Join Availability on Availability.Staff_Id = Staff.StaffId
```